# How can I get the selected option name or id of a select element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I have a "questionairre" that is made up of a series of select boxes.

I need to use two properties in the options. For each selected option I need the value (which I know how to get and is working fine) but I also need to store an additional value which represents the id of the specific option in a DB.

One solution would be to put the two values in the "value" property and parse it out, but if there is some other property I can use that might be easier and clearer. Can I add a custom property like `databaseId` that could be accessed with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

I would not add custom attributes as this would not be valid HTML anymore.

Can't you use the "normal" ID attribute (i.e. the one that any HTML element has) of these `option` elements?
You could also prefix the ID if it is necessary and take a substring of the ID, e.g.

```
<option id="db23123" value="value">Value</option>
```

---

Or depending how your `select` is structured, you could also use the `value` attribute for the database ID and put the other "value" as text inside the option (if it is human readable):

```
<option value="23123">Human Readable Value</option>
```

Then you can get the DB ID via `.val()` and the text value via `.text()`.

---

Another solution that works if you e.g. create the `option` elements dynamically via JavaScript is to use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) functionality. This allows you to attach arbitrary key-value pairs to any DOM node.

Comment: Sorry ,  I deleted my original comment before I saw your jFiddle. It does work, but I just think it needs to be clear to the developer how to access it.  The jFiddle you show accesses a generic 'option' element, but if there is more than one option element, it concatenates all results together.  What I 'think' the original post aimed at was getting the id of a selected element, which is something like ("#my_selector :selected").attr("id"); ....unless I'm mistaken or mis-read, which is entirely possible.

Comment: @Shem: Yes, of course, but I expect someone using `.text` to know this. The documentation says *"Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements."* If you want the text of a specific (single) element, you have to only select that one. But yeah, I agree that I didn't show how to get the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [metadata-plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata).

You could then use like so:

Markup:

```
<select>
  <option class="{db_id: 1}" name="X" value="y" selected="selected">
  [...]
</select>
```

Script:

```
  var data = $('option:selected').metadata();
  alert(data.db_id);
```